# how could i get both the final hidden state and sequence in a LSTM layer when using a bidirectional wrapper

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

i have followed the steps in https://machinelearningmastery.com/return-sequences-and-return-states-for-lstms-in-keras/
But when it comes to the Bidirectional lstm, i tried this

```
lstm, state_h, state_c = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, return_state= True))(input)
```

but it won't work.

is there some approach to  get both the final hidden state and sequence in a  LSTM layer when using a bidirectional wrapper

Comment: Bidirectional wrapper creates two copies of given layer, `forward_layer` and `backward_layer`. I can't check it now but I'm pretty sure you can get hidden states using `my_bidirectional_layer.forward_layer.states` or something similar.

Comment: Which Keras version do you use?

Comment: 2.1.5 keras with a 1.4.0 tensorflow backend

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The call `Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, return_state=True))(input)` returns 5 tensors:

1. The entire sequence of hidden states, by default it'll be the concatenation of forward and backward states.
2. The last hidden state `h` for the forward LSTM
3. The last cell state `c` for the forward LSTM
4. The last hidden state `h` for the backward LSTM
5. The last cell state `c` for the backward LSTM

The line you've posted would raise an error since you want to unpack the returned value into just three variables (`lstm, state_h, state_c`).

To correct it, simply unpack the returned value into 5 variables. If you want to merge the states, you can concatenate the forward and backward states with `Concatenate` layers.

```
lstm, forward_h, forward_c, backward_h, backward_c = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, return_state=True))(input)
state_h = Concatenate()([forward_h, backward_h])
state_c = Concatenate()([forward_c, backward_c])
```

Comment: when you say 1 is the entire sequence of hidden states, do you mean that (in the case of concatenation), it is 2 followed by 4?

Comment: @Michaela Nope. If the input is a sequence of length T, then 1 will also be a sequence of length T. On the other hand, 2 and 4 will both have length 1, they're the output at a single time step.

Comment: I'm realizing that in my application, `return_sequences=False`, so nevermind, sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: Can someone please provide with the documentation of this, I looked for it without finding it, thanks